# Keras using too much memory

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a keras (with tensorflow backend) model which is defined like so:

```
INPUT_SHAPE = [4740, 3540, 1]

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3),
                 activation='relu',
                 input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(Conv2D(2, (4, 4), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(4, (4, 4), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(8, (4, 4), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(16, (4, 4), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (4, 4), strides=(1, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss=keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adadelta(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

This model has only 37,506 trainable params. Yet somehow it is able to deplete K80's 12GB vram resource on model.fit() if a batch size is more then 1.
Why does this model need so much memory?
And how do I calculate memory requirements properly?
The function from [How to determine needed memory of Keras model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137288/how-to-determine-needed-memory-of-keras-model) gives me 2.15 GB per 1 element in a batch. So at least I should be able to make a batch of 5.

EDIT: model.summary()

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 4738, 3538, 32)    320       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 4735, 3535, 2)     1026      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 1183, 883, 2)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 1180, 880, 4)      132       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 295, 220, 4)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 292, 217, 8)       520       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 73, 54, 8)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 70, 51, 16)        2064      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_4 (MaxPooling2 (None, 17, 12, 16)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 14, 9, 32)         8224      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_5 (MaxPooling2 (None, 3, 2, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 3, 2, 32)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 192)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 128)               24704     
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 128)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 4)                 516       
=================================================================
Total params: 37,506
Trainable params: 37,506
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: How do you run your experiment? Are you sure that your memory is freed after a single model compilation?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko Yes, I'm sure that it's freed, I check nvidia-smi before running the model.fit(). And what do you mean by how?

Comment: E.g. if you run your training in jupyter notebook - you could have problems with garbage collection and freeing the memory of old models.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I did try to restart kernel and also restart notebook before running fit.

Comment: Can you share the output of model.summary() ?

Comment: Running fit in this model with one image takes 35GB here....

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro edited

Comment: @DanielMöller How did you determine that? 
And why then I can run fit with one image on 12GB?

Comment: I just looked at my resource manager while running. (CPU, float32)

Comment: @DanielMöller thank you, this seems to be a suitable but no ideal way to determine requirements.

Comment: Try to change `adadelta` to `sgd`.

Comment: @MarcinMożejko still running out of memory.

Comment: Could you share your notebook on e.g. `github`?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko
https://gist.github.com/UpmostScarab/1e23244bae13e68eb0a95dae0ee24542

Comment: what is the size of you data?

Comment: @Paddy well the image size is stated in my question and it's 4740*3540 and with 32 bit precision one image is about 52 MB

Comment: Keras probably has way more variables than we can see...maybe duplicate helpers for the convolutions, probably gradient vars too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output shape of the first layer is B*4738*3538*32 (B is the batch size), which will take around 1GB * B memory. The gradients and other activations will probably take some memory too. Maybe increasing the stride for the first layer will help.

Comment: Thank you, actually I shouldn't have made the first layer so deep. Reducing that helped.

Comment: what is the stride?