# batch size setting during training

Tags: keras, gpu

When I am training using keras + tensorflow-gpu, and I set the batch_size to 128, which is the max size the gpu could accept, otherwise, there's OOM problem. My question is when the batch_size is 128, the pics size is 128*224*224*3*4(the img size is 224*224, in RGB channel), total is around 10M Bytes, which I think is too small compared to the memory of GPU. Is there any explanation for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgetting `3` more things which also require GPU memory.

1. Your Model weights.
2. Temporary variables during calculation of gradients.

These two take up a huge chunk of memory.
This is why even though your batch consumes `10M`.

3. There are so many other minute things that require GPU memory.

Comment: great explanation

Answer (score 1):

The image is uint where is tensor is float64 which increases size by eight times. Forward path, gradients, and other tensors use a significant chunk of memory.

You can compute memory required for your model as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137288/how-to-determine-needed-memory-of-keras-model?rq=1)