# Keras - improve memory performance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, out-of-memory, conv-neural-network

I am running a convolutional neural network on input set that is `5GB`, and training output is same size, so total of 10GB of data. I am reserving about `50GB` of memory, but still getting memory issues. I am using adam optimizer, my model fitting looks like this:

```
cnn_model.fit(x_train,y_train, validation_data=(x_test,y_test), callbacks=[earlystopper], epochs=25)
```

Any idea how I can improve the situation? Someone here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18736 says "Adam and RMSProp are problematic because they memorize historical gradients", any ideas how to address that?

Comment: Have you counted the memory used up by intermediate layers in both forward and backward propagation?

Comment: No, how would I do that, and how would I use that info? Please explain

Comment: Let;s say you take input a `224 x 224 x 3` image and pass it through a `3 x 3 x 64` conv layer (with zero-padding to maintain the size) followed by a `2 x 2` maxpool, the output of these two layers will be `112 x 112 x 64`. Now, if you have 32 images, the output of the max-pool layer will occupy `32 x 112 x 112 x 64 = 25690112` bytes ~ 25 MB. You have to account for all such intermediate outputs. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137288/how-to-determine-needed-memory-of-keras-model) to determine memory used since it can get quite complicated. You can reduce batch size if needed.

Comment: Are there any flags I can pass to minimize storing of intermediate data, or saving previous iteration's state whenever possible?

Comment: I think we need more information to help you, like which model are you training, the size and number of images (not total size as you gave), and training parameters. Are you training on CPU or GPU? Please also include the real unedited out of memory errors.

Comment: I am using CPU, training on 1000 images that are 2048x2048, total size 5 GB.

Comment: What is the batch size and how much CPU ram do you have? Also, how much memory is being used if you set ?`batch_size = 1`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to load the whole dataset at once! I would create a flow generator for training and testing.
Something like this: https://www.kaggle.com/humananalog/keras-generator-for-reading-directly-from-bson