# Tensorflow maximum input layer size

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, input

At which order of magnitude the number of elements in the input vector of a Tensorflow neural network becomes computationally impracticable when using low specs (e.g. 2.60GHz & 6GB RAM)?

For example, I know that 1,000 input cells are ok, but what about 100K? Or 1M?

Comment: If you start having so many inputs, it is long-past time to start thinking about dimesion reduction in any case. Either by designing the Neural Network in a more efficient manner (convolutions, pooling layers etc.) or by using oldschool methods such as PCA to reduce dimensionality before you feed the NN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a trade-off between training time, accuracy, available ram, data size ...etc.

The complexity of the model vs the size of the data is known as the bias/variance trade-off, and you can read more about it [here](https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/bias-and-variance-in-machine-learning-51fdd38d1f86). But it is normally good practice to start off simple, and then add complexity as long as the model keeps improving.
If the input dimension has a high number of classes (like words in text) consider using embedding (or other methods) to reduce the dimension.

Assuming you have a sufficient large data set, enough time to train, and can choose your model infinitely complex, only restricted by ram, then following is a ram analysis.

The model ram size is dependent on the network architecture, dtype and batch size.
To test the required memory size to train your network, you can use the function from ZFTurbo's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43137288/how-to-determine-needed-memory-of-keras-model), with a copy below.

```
def get_model_memory_usage(batch_size, model):
    import numpy as np
    from tensorflow.keras import backend as K

    shapes_mem_count = 0
    for l in model.layers:
        single_layer_mem = 1
        for s in l.output_shape:
            if s is None:
                continue
            single_layer_mem *= s
        shapes_mem_count += single_layer_mem

    trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.trainable_weights)])
    non_trainable_count = np.sum([K.count_params(p) for p in set(model.non_trainable_weights)])

    number_size = 4.0
    if K.floatx() == 'float16':
         number_size = 2.0
    if K.floatx() == 'float64':
         number_size = 8.0

    total_memory = number_size*(batch_size*shapes_mem_count + trainable_count + non_trainable_count)
    gbytes = np.round(total_memory / (1024.0 ** 3), 3)
    return gbytes
```

Now we can easily test different setup, and it's corresponding ram size required. Below is an example 2 hidden layers, dtype is float32, batch size is 256 and where we set the first hidden layer size to 1k, 10k, 100k and 1000k, which results in the corresponding 0.06, 0.052, 0.517 and 5.16 GB ram required for training.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K

K.set_floatx('float32')

n_input_nodes = [1e3, 1e4, 1e5, 1e6]

for n in n_input_nodes:
    inputs = Input(shape=(1000,))
    x = Dense(n, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    outputs = Dense(1)(x)

    model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')

    print(get_model_memory_usage(128, model))
```